# Weird selectableItemBackgroundBorderless ripple effect

Tags: android, ripple

I'm using selectableItemBackgroundBorderless  as background on one of my views and it behaves weird on click. Here's a video, it changes it's behaviour on every other click, the first one is wrong, second one is the way I expect it to work.

[Sample expained on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BERPvWPEECE&feature=youtu.be)

and this is the layout

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_4dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_down"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_24dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_24dp"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_4dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: what is weird about it? the video does not show anything weird.

Comment: watch the ripple effect closely, every other click has different behaviour (different ripple), first (third and fifth) is wrong, second (fourth and sixth) are correct